# How to clear the file contents after reading

Tags: powershell

The operation of reading data and the subsequent cleaning of the file must be in one session. and other processes should not have access to the file.

```
$FileTwo = [System.io.File]::Open('C:\FiLeTwo.txt', "Open", "Read", "None") 
$FileTwo2 = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($FileTwo)
$text = $text + $FileTwo2.ReadToEnd()

$text = $text -replace '\ ' -replace 'g' -replace '\(' -replace '\)' -replace $re, "" #-replace '\n'
# Set-Content 'C:\FiLeTwo.txt' "" -Force 
# IN that moment I need to clear the file. 
# But I need cleare the file and,  after, close the File ($FileTwo.Close())

$FileTwo.Close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't even need to use so many streams:

```
$path = 'C:\FiLeTwo.txt'
$text = Get-Content $path -Raw
Clear-Content $path
$text = $text -Replace ...
```

If you want to use a `FileStream`, you can also use `SetLength` to erase the contents:

```
# open with "ReadWrite"
$fileTwo = [System.IO.File]::Open("C:\FiLeTwo.txt", "Open", "ReadWrite", "None") 
try {
    # ... read, replace etc ...
    # clear the contents:
    $fileTwo.SetLength(0);
}
finally {
    # make sure to put this in a finally block!
    $fileTwo.Dispose()
}
```

(Make sure to dispose *all* your streams properly in a finally block!)

Comment: This is what i need - $fileTwo.SetLength(0); 
I need blok the file for other application.
Thank you Marsze!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Clear-Content` to erase the content of your file, but not deleting it.

Example:
`Clear-Content c:\path\to\your\file.txt`

You can read more about it here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/clear-content?view=powershell-6